# laravel 5 get current language id in controller

Tags: php, laravel

i'm new to laravel, and i'm wondering how to get the language_id (primary key "id" in database) by current lang_code (a column of language table).

in my language model, i created a function like this :

```
public function getLang($lang_code = null) {
     $lang_code = App::getLocale();
     return SELF::with($lang_code)->get();
}
```

in the homeController, i added this line of code:

```
    $lang = Language::with('getLang');
    echo $lang->id;
```

Got errors:

```
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$id', '/home/otherraylinux/public_html/starter/app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php', '52', array('articles' => object(Collection), 'lang' => object(Builder))) in HomeController.php line 52
```

*edit*
The actual things i want to do is:

```
$lang = DB::table('languages')->select('id')->where('lang_code', '=', App::getLocale())->get();
echo $lang[0]->id;
```

*edit*

What is the problem? And what is the best practice to get the id ? i know the above code should not be good in practice.

Comment: can you show me your migrations file for the Language table ?, and try to return not echo

Comment: @Arlind here https://github.com/mrakodol/Laravel-5-Bootstrap-3-Starter-Site/blob/master/database/migrations/2014_10_18_195027_create_languages_table.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Query scope in laravel 5

**Model**

```
public function scopeLangCode($query, $lang_code)
{
    return $query->where('lang_code', $lang_code);
}
```

**Controller**

```
$lang = Language::langCode(App::getLocale())->first();
echo $lang->id;
```

More details about Query Scope: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#query-scopes

Is this what you are looking for?